# is Android 9 end of support

Tags: 9.0-pie

I am wondering if Android 9 is end-of-support. I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Pie) that it is end-of-support since Mar 7 2022.

Also on https://endoflife.date/android, but I cannot find any official link.

Does anyone know the official link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286713/is-there-a-documented-life-cycle-for-which-android-versions-receive-security-upd

Comment: thank you so much